# global is undefined running tests with mocha for babel compiled code

Tags: mocha.js, global, babeljs

I have a node js library that is compiled with Babel, has mocha tests that run fine. Now I have another app, react redux... that is using the library, included as a dependency in package.json, works fine  no problem, BUT when I try to run its own tests (with mocha './test/**/*.spec.js' --compilers js:babel-register) gives an compilation error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT' of undefined
at a line of included compiled lib where is some code from Buffer module used by Babel:

```
Buffer.TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT = global.TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT !== undefined
  ? global.TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT
  : typedArraySupport()
```

and global is the undefined var.

Comment: was caused by the bunyan logger used by the included lib, that included some Buffer module and there global was replaced => undefined

Comment: You should probably make that your answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

was caused by the bunyan logger used by the included lib, that included some Buffer module and there global was replaced => undefined –